# Show integrability of function

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and an increasing sequence $(u_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu$. Let $u=\sup_{n}u_{n}$. I am asked to argue (or argue against) that $u \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$.

**My attempt**

Basically I am trying to show that given the conditions above, if the sequence $(u_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing and its elements are in $\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$ then the limit of the sequence is also in $\mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$.

Using the monotone convergence theorem I have concluded that $u \notin \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$ since given the assumptions above $u \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$ if and only if $\sup_n \int u_{n} d\mu < \infty$ and this condition is not met.

Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use Monotone because you are not told that those functions are nonnegative.

Comment: Your argument is fine except that you have to look at $u_n-u_1$ instead of $u_n$ itself to make the functions non-negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial counterexample is like, $u_{n}(x)=n$ and then $u(x)=\infty$ everywhere and so $u\notin L^{1}(\mu)$ for any $\mu$.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Could you also comment on my argument? Does it hold?